# android how to work with color picker Dialog

Tags: android, color-picker

I have an app where i am able to draw on screen.
I want option menu color chooser option should be there. by choosing color from there will able to draw using that color.
So i want to put a colorPicker dialog there how can I use that plz give me some sample example.

(I go through ColorPicker available in android developer resources but I want some customize and how to use within an avtivity)

Thank you

Comment: I want color should be present in a gridview style. How can I do that plz give me a way

Comment: May be this will work for you 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16363235/android-color-picker-to-be-included-in-the-activity

Comment: Try out this one..May be it will solve your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16363235/android-color-picker-to-be-included-in-the-activity

Comment: Would recommend checking [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16363314/11845778).

Answer (score 3):

I like this one most: http://code.google.com/p/android-color-picker/

Answer (score 0):

For those who want a fragment solution, I have made a fork of **android-color-picker** where **DialogFragment** is used and is re-created on configuration change. Here's the link: https://github.com/lomza/android-color-picker