# Android color picker to be included in the activity

Tags: java, android, colors, paint

I would like to include a color picker in my paint program. So anyone here has already done something like this please give me some tutorials or piece of code to get me started. I really need to get the whole idea of adding this. I already have set up the canvas for the drawing so I'd like to add the color picker to it. Any ideas are welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your class should implement  ColorPickerDialog.OnColorChangedListener

```
  public class MainActivity implements ColorPickerDialog.OnColorChangedListener
  {
       private Paint mPaint;  

        mPaint = new Paint();
       // on button click
        new ColorPickerDialog(this, this, mPaint.getColor()).show();

  }
```

ColorPicker Dialog

```
public class ColorPickerDialog extends Dialog {

public interface OnColorChangedListener {
    void colorChanged(int color);
}

private OnColorChangedListener mListener;
private int mInitialColor;

private static class ColorPickerView extends View {
    private Paint mPaint;
    private Paint mCenterPaint;
    private final int[] mColors;
    private OnColorChangedListener mListener;

    ColorPickerView(Context c, OnColorChangedListener l, int color) {
        super(c);
        mListener = l;
        mColors = new int[] {
            0xFFFF0000, 0xFFFF00FF, 0xFF0000FF, 0xFF00FFFF, 0xFF00FF00,
            0xFFFFFF00, 0xFFFF0000
        };
        Shader s = new SweepGradient(0, 0, mColors, null);

        mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mPaint.setShader(s);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(32);

        mCenterPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mCenterPaint.setColor(color);
        mCenterPaint.setStrokeWidth(5);
    }

    private boolean mTrackingCenter;
    private boolean mHighlightCenter;

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        float r = CENTER_X - mPaint.getStrokeWidth()*0.5f;

        canvas.translate(CENTER_X, CENTER_X);

        canvas.drawOval(new RectF(-r, -r, r, r), mPaint);
        canvas.drawCircle(0, 0, CENTER_RADIUS, mCenterPaint);

        if (mTrackingCenter) {
            int c = mCenterPaint.getColor();
            mCenterPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

            if (mHighlightCenter) {
                mCenterPaint.setAlpha(0xFF);
            } else {
                mCenterPaint.setAlpha(0x80);
            }
            canvas.drawCircle(0, 0,
                              CENTER_RADIUS + mCenterPaint.getStrokeWidth(),
                              mCenterPaint);

            mCenterPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            mCenterPaint.setColor(c);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        setMeasuredDimension(CENTER_X*2, CENTER_Y*2);
    }

    private static final int CENTER_X = 100;
    private static final int CENTER_Y = 100;
    private static final int CENTER_RADIUS = 32;

    private int floatToByte(float x) {
        int n = java.lang.Math.round(x);
        return n;
    }
    private int pinToByte(int n) {
        if (n < 0) {
            n = 0;
        } else if (n > 255) {
            n = 255;
        }
        return n;
    }

    private int ave(int s, int d, float p) {
        return s + java.lang.Math.round(p * (d - s));
    }

    private int interpColor(int colors[], float unit) {
        if (unit <= 0) {
            return colors[0];
        }
        if (unit >= 1) {
            return colors[colors.length - 1];
        }

        float p = unit * (colors.length - 1);
        int i = (int)p;
        p -= i;

        // now p is just the fractional part [0...1) and i is the index
        int c0 = colors[i];
        int c1 = colors[i+1];
        int a = ave(Color.alpha(c0), Color.alpha(c1), p);
        int r = ave(Color.red(c0), Color.red(c1), p);
        int g = ave(Color.green(c0), Color.green(c1), p);
        int b = ave(Color.blue(c0), Color.blue(c1), p);

        return Color.argb(a, r, g, b);
    }

    private int rotateColor(int color, float rad) {
        float deg = rad * 180 / 3.1415927f;
        int r = Color.red(color);
        int g = Color.green(color);
        int b = Color.blue(color);

        ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix();
        ColorMatrix tmp = new ColorMatrix();

        cm.setRGB2YUV();
        tmp.setRotate(0, deg);
        cm.postConcat(tmp);
        tmp.setYUV2RGB();
        cm.postConcat(tmp);

        final float[] a = cm.getArray();

        int ir = floatToByte(a[0] * r +  a[1] * g +  a[2] * b);
        int ig = floatToByte(a[5] * r +  a[6] * g +  a[7] * b);
        int ib = floatToByte(a[10] * r + a[11] * g + a[12] * b);

        return Color.argb(Color.alpha(color), pinToByte(ir),
                          pinToByte(ig), pinToByte(ib));
    }

    private static final float PI = 3.1415926f;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX() - CENTER_X;
        float y = event.getY() - CENTER_Y;
        boolean inCenter = java.lang.Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y) <= CENTER_RADIUS;

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                mTrackingCenter = inCenter;
                if (inCenter) {
                    mHighlightCenter = true;
                    invalidate();
                    break;
                }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (mTrackingCenter) {
                    if (mHighlightCenter != inCenter) {
                        mHighlightCenter = inCenter;
                        invalidate();
                    }
                } else {
                    float angle = (float)java.lang.Math.atan2(y, x);
                    // need to turn angle [-PI ... PI] into unit [0....1]
                    float unit = angle/(2*PI);
                    if (unit < 0) {
                        unit += 1;
                    }
                    mCenterPaint.setColor(interpColor(mColors, unit));
                    invalidate();
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                if (mTrackingCenter) {
                    if (inCenter) {
                        mListener.colorChanged(mCenterPaint.getColor());
                    }
                    mTrackingCenter = false;    // so we draw w/o halo
                    invalidate();
                }
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}

public ColorPickerDialog(Context context,
                         OnColorChangedListener listener,
                         int initialColor) {
    super(context);

    mListener = listener;
    mInitialColor = initialColor;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    OnColorChangedListener l = new OnColorChangedListener() {
        public void colorChanged(int color) {
            mListener.colorChanged(color);
            dismiss();
        }
    };

    setContentView(new ColorPickerView(getContext(), l, mInitialColor));
    setTitle("Pick a Color");
}
```

You have to choose the color and click the center circle to pick the color. Set the color to your paint object and use the same to draw.

Snap shot

[image]

Edit 2:

Source code can be found at https://code.google.com/p/android-color-picker/

Another ColorPickerDialog

```
   public class ColorPickerDialog extends AlertDialog implements
    ColorPickerView.OnColorChangedListener {

private ColorPickerView mColorPicker;

private ColorPanelView mOldColor;
private ColorPanelView mNewColor;

private OnColorChangedListener mListener;

public ColorPickerDialog(Context myDrawingMenuOptionEventsListener, int initialColor) {
    super(myDrawingMenuOptionEventsListener);

    init(initialColor);
}

private void init(int color) {
    // To fight color branding.
    getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);

    setUp(color);

}

private void setUp(int color) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_color_picker, null);
    layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    setView(layout);

    setTitle("Choose a Color");
    // setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info);

    mColorPicker = (ColorPickerView) layout
            .findViewById(R.id.color_picker_view);
    mOldColor = (ColorPanelView) layout.findViewById(R.id.old_color_panel);
    mNewColor = (ColorPanelView) layout.findViewById(R.id.new_color_panel);

    ((LinearLayout) mOldColor.getParent()).setPadding(Math
            .round(mColorPicker.getDrawingOffset()), 0, Math
            .round(mColorPicker.getDrawingOffset()), 0);

    mColorPicker.setOnColorChangedListener(this);

    mOldColor.setColor(color);
    mColorPicker.setColor(color, true);

}

@Override
public void onColorChanged(int color) {

    mNewColor.setColor(color);

    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onColorChanged(color);
    }

}

public void setAlphaSliderVisible(boolean visible) {
    mColorPicker.setAlphaSliderVisible(visible);
}

public int getColor() {
    return mColorPicker.getColor();
}

 }
```

Usage :

```
        final ColorPickerDialog d= new ColorPickerDialog(ActivityName.this,0xffffffff);
                d.setAlphaSliderVisible(true);

                d.setButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        mPaint.setColor(d.getColor());

                    }
                });

                d.setButton2("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    }
                });

                d.show();
```

Snap shot:

[image: Snap2]

In the above choose the color on the right bar. You also make a choice how dark or light the color choosen should be. Click ok to set the paint to your paint object and use the same to draw. Cancel will dismiss the color picker dialog.

Edit 3:

Only change instead of clear function i have added color picker on click of clear button.

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ColorPickerDialog.OnColorChangedListener {

DrawingView dv ;
RelativeLayout rl;   
private Paint       mPaint;
private MaskFilter  mEmboss;
private MaskFilter  mBlur;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    dv = new DrawingView(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint.setDither(true);
    mPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(12);
    rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl);
    rl.addView(dv);
    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    //b.setText(R.string.France);
    Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    rl.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              // dv.clear();    
             new ColorPickerDialog(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.this, mPaint.getColor()).show();


        }

    });

    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            AlertDialog.Builder editalert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            editalert.setTitle("Please Enter the name with which you want to Save");
            final EditText input = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
            input.setLayoutParams(lp);
            editalert.setView(input);
            editalert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    rl.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                    String name= input.getText().toString();
                    Bitmap bitmap =rl.getDrawingCache();
                    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
                    File myDir = new File(root + "/MyDraw");    
                    myDir.mkdirs();
                    File file = new File (myDir, name+".png");
                    if (file.exists ()) file.delete ();         
                    try 
                    {
                        if(!file.exists())
                    {
                        file.createNewFile();
                    }
                        FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 10, ostream);
                       // System.out.println("saving......................................................"+path);
                        ostream.close();
                        rl.invalidate();                            
                    } 
                    catch (Exception e) 
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }finally
                    {

                       rl.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);                            
                    }
                }
            });
            editalert.show();   
        }

    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

 public class DrawingView extends View {

        private static final float MINP = 0.25f;
        private static final float MAXP = 0.75f;
        private Bitmap  mBitmap;
        private Canvas  mCanvas;
        private Path    mPath;
        private Paint   mBitmapPaint;
        Context context;
        private Paint circlePaint;
        private Path circlePath;

        public DrawingView(Context c) {
        super(c);
        context=c;
        mPath = new Path();
        mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);  
         circlePaint = new Paint();
         circlePath = new Path();
         circlePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
         circlePaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
         circlePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
         circlePaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.MITER);
         circlePaint.setStrokeWidth(4f); 

        }

        @Override
         protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);

        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);

        canvas.drawPath(circlePath, circlePaint);
        }

        private float mX, mY;
        private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

        private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
        mPath.reset();
        mPath.moveTo(x, y);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
        }
        private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
        float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
        if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
            mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX)/2, (y + mY)/2);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;

             circlePath.reset();
             circlePath.addCircle(mX, mY, 30, Path.Direction.CW); 
             invalidate();

        }
        }
        private void touch_up() {
        mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
        circlePath.reset();
        // commit the path to our offscreen
        mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        // kill this so we don't double draw
        mPath.reset();

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                touch_start(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                touch_move(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                touch_up();
                invalidate();
                break;
        }
        return true;
        }  
        }
@Override
public void colorChanged(int color) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mPaint.setColor(color);
}
  }
```

[image]

Comment: its not working...i have tried as below;                                                                        color.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    myplate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    new ColorPicker(MainActivity.this,null, mPaint.getColor()).show();
   }
  });

Comment: @Raghunandan Can you please add the `ColorPickerView's` source?

Comment: @Raghunandan I am trying to compile your second example but unfortunately it seems that I am missing some sources and I don't know how to fix this. Can you please provide the entire compilable code of your second example?

Comment: @Try_me34 have you read the post. The source is available at  https://code.google.com/p/android-color-picker/

Comment: @Raghunandan In `Edit : 3 ` i'm trying to use `mPath.reset()` but it's not working. pls help how to clear drawing in your edit-3

Comment: @Aks4125 ask a different question and post the details of what you have tried.

Comment: Thanks for grate solution, i am using it. But if i have a color code and  i want to calculate x and y position of that color in Oval. Actually have to show point on last selected color.

Comment: @HradeshKumar you can look a the second colorpicker which shows a circle on selecting a circle and build your own

Answer (score 1):

you have a google code which can help you

http://code.google.com/p/android-color-picker/

Answer (score 0):

I used this link for color picker http://code.google.com/p/android-color-picker/
steps:

I've added some extra file(like:"android-mvn-push.gradle" ) you can skip that file in step 3
and also remove this "apply from: '../android-mvn-push.gradle' " from your bulid.gradle(Module:liabrary) file if your skipping step 3.

1. Go to the above link and download project as zip file and extract the zip.
2. Inside Extracted folder you'll see library folder.
3. Copy that folder into your android Applications main folder where it contains all its gradle n all... and also copy "android-mvn-push.gradle" file to your main project folder.
4. open bulid.gradle(Module:app) inside that add dependencies like this, 
   "compile project(':library')"
5. update Settings.Gradle with include ':app', ':library'
6. go to Tools>Android>Sync with Gradles and then it will show some error like build gradle not matching bla bla....
7. Click on that open file error option.
8. In your bulid.gradle(Module:liabrary) change this,

   apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion propCompileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion propBuildToolsVersion

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion propMinSdkVersion
    targetSdkVersion propTargetSdkVersion
    versionCode propVersionCode
    versionName propVersionName
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

apply from: '../android-mvn-push.gradle'

To>>>>>>>>>>>

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}
apply from: '../android-mvn-push.gradle'

Finally Tools>Android > Sync with gradle...
and Bingo....It Works ....!!!