# How to show a list of color's to chose from

Tags: android, android-layout

How to show a list of color's to chose from .
i have a list view with colored text [user has option to choose color they want .]

```
String available_colors[]={"#FF0000","#00FF00","#0000FF"};
String  color_options[]={"Red","Green","Blue"};

SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putInt("selected_color",position); 



SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
        selected_color= preferences.getInt("selected_color", 0);
        msg.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(available_colors[selected_color]));
```

how can i make a more ittutive color picker  color choser ??

Comment: I think you are searching for a color picker. Have you looked into this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442407/android-color-picker ?

Comment: answered a question on color picker @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16363235/android-color-picker-to-be-included-in-the-activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the wheel color picker in the [apidemo](http://developer.android.com/tools/samples/index.html) example. The sample app is provided with your sdk. run and check it out